# Adding Express as a javascript library to WebStorm 6

Tags: express, webstorm

Can any one show me how to add `Express` as a javascript library to Web Storm 6. I've installed `Expresss` via `npm`. Then in Web Storm preferences I've added a new library called `Express` and attached the `node_modules/express` folder.

But Web Storm still complains that it cannot resolve methods like `express.bodyParser()` etc.

I also don't know what to specify for the `Documentation URL` for the `Express` library.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what do you mean by add Express library.If you plan to link global express installation I wouldn't recommend it. My recommendation is to

1 install express globally by using the command line/terminal

```
 npm install -g express
```

2 Then use the command line to create express application

```
express myapp
```

3 Install dependencies

```
cd myapp && npm install
```

4 Open myapp directory with Webstorm using File -> Open Directory

If you already have the application check your package.json in your application root directory it should contain express in its dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "description": "hello world test app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.x"
  }
}
```

if the express is missing add it in your package json then do npm install

Comment: When I say "add Express Library" I mean in the Web Storm IDE. I've npm installed everything and all works fine. But Web Storm allows you to add javascript libraries so that it can add 'intellisense'. So that if I typed 'express' followed by a dot it would present me with a list of appropriate methods like bodyParse(), methodOveride() etc.

Comment: Oh, it appears its currently an Open issue ... http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6667